# Какой суффикс в глаголе ПРЕРЫВАТЬ?

Tags: морфология, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, аспектология

Если глагол *прерывать* образован от глагола *прервать*, то проводя аналогии с другими цепочками (*разыскать* -- *разыскивать*, *опоздать* -- *опаздывать*) можно ли сказать, что в глаголе *прерывать* суффикс *-ыва-*, который накладывается на корень *-рыв-*?

Answer (score 1):

> в глаголе прерывать суффикс -ыва-, который накладывается на корень -рыв-?

Да, в первом приближении именно так. Для школы такое понимание вполне уместно. Говорить, что "рыв" чистый корень нельзя, поскольку "ыва" - мотивирующий элемент формы несовершенного вида.

Но если посмотреть глубже, то "рыв" здесь вообще не корень с исторической точки зрения. Здесь форма корня "-рыв-" вторична, первичной была бы "-рв-". по общей схеме Несовершенный вид образовывался бы как **прервать-прер(в)ывать**, но "рв" перед "ы" фонетически упростилось до р, как и в ряде других случаев. При этом, однако, надо иметь ввиду, что само это в - тоже не исконное, а вставное на стыке (зиянии) гласных, но это еще более ранняя история.

Почти точный аналог - глагол звать. **Звать-подозвать-подзывать<подзвыват**ь. При этом есть отзыв, позыв.

Что-то похожее и с глаголом **плыть-приплыть-приплывать**, но тут дело много сложнее, поскольку, во-первых, у "плыть" три, если не четыре формы корня, а во-вторых, это глагол движения и возникает опасность смешения еще и форм "плыть" и "плавать."
Но в целом схема та же. ***плыть-заплыть-заплывать***.  Вряд ли кто будет считать "плыв" в последнем глаголе корнем, хотя есть "однокоренные" заплыв и плывун.

Answer (score 0):

Корень "рыв", а суффикс "а".
[https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=прерывать](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Да и однокоренные слова — *перерыв, срыв, непрерывно*. Корень — "рыв".

При образовании слов и форм звуковой облик слова может меняться:
Ср.: *книга – книжечка; пахать – пашу; светить – свеча, освещение; **рот – рта***.
https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/645-22_koren_slova.html

Comment: А какой тогда способ словообразования, если суффикс не меняется —  "корнеизменительный"?

Comment: Это не словообразование, а просто изменение формы глагола (*прерывать* - несовершенная, а *прервать* - совершенная). Просто из корня выпадает гласная, как при склонении существительных (*рот/рта*).